# print array in clockwise

Tags: c#, arrays

I Have this code is receive the array from TextBox and then print it in the clockwise ,but doesn't print in correct way when I make trace to this code I Don't have error but when run it don't show the result in a clockwise I Don't know where the error

```
int i, k = 0, l = 0;
int m=4; 
int n=4;

/*  k - starting row index
    m - ending row index
    l - starting column index
    n - ending column index
    i - iterator
*/


string [,]a = new string[4,4];
string s = null;

for(int q=0;q<=4;q++){
    for(int j=0;j<=4;j++){
        a[q,j] = textBox1.Text[q].ToString();
    }
}

while (k < m && l < n)
{
    /* Print the first row from the remaining rows */
    for (i = l; i < n; i++)
    {
        s += a[k, i].ToString();
    }

    k++;

    /* Print the last column from the remaining columns */
    for (i = k; i < m; i++)
    {
        s += a[i, n - 1].ToString();
    }
    n--;

    /* Print the last row from the remaining rows */
    if (k < m)
    {
        for (i = n - 1; i >= l; i--)
        {
            s += a[m - 1, i].ToString();
        }
        m--;
    }

    /* Print the first column from the remaining columns */
    if (l < n)
    {
        for (i = m - 1; i >= k; i--)
        {
            s += a[i, l].ToString();
        }
        l++;
    }
    richTextBox1.Text = s.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it? If you don't know how, this is an excellent time to learn it.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the actual and of the expected output, please?

Comment: when I enter sendhelpsoon the result be ssssndddneee

Comment: and it must be like this SEND
 OONH
 SPLE

Comment: Could you explain what logic you try to implement? Because I don't see the clue of converting sendhelpsoon to SEND OONH SPLE. And what do you mean by clockwise, Alphabetic ascending?

Comment: I have array send help soon ,Iwant to print it in  clockwise the array must be  SEND OONH SPLE

Answer (score 2):

If your target text is SEND OONH SPLE given SEND HELP SOON this looks like a spiral in a matrix with 4 cols and 3 rows:

```
    0   1   2   3
0   S   E   N   D
1   O   O   N   H
2   S   P   L   E
```

Your code doesn't seem to work with a likely input (though you have incorrect sizes at 4x4, it's 4x3, let's assume a likely input is SEND/nHELP/nSOON). e.g.

```
    0   1   2   3
0   S   E   N   D
1   H   E   L   P
2   S   O   O   N
```

Let's also assume you populate "a" succesfully with this, your algorithm is then appending to an output string the first row (forwards), last column (downwards), last row (backwards), then first column (upwards) - but that will give, as you see above, SENDPNOOSHEL, not SENDOONHSPLE.

Here is some code to achieve the requested result in a more generic way. The idea of the algorithm is to fill the array going right and then down, and the left and up, changing direction each time a boundary is hit, and then reducing the accessible size so as not to overwrite data already written.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{   
    string text = "SENDHELPSOON";
    Queue<char> chars = new Queue<char>();
    foreach (char letter in text)
            chars.Enqueue(letter);

    char[,] resultMatrix = new char[3, 4];
    int maxX = resultMatrix.GetLength(1);
    int maxY = resultMatrix.GetLength(0);
    int minX = 0; int minY = 0; int x = 0; int y = 0;
    int direction = 1;       

    if ((maxY * maxX) < chars.Count)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Not enough space in the output matrix");

    while (chars.Count > 0)
    {            
        // going across (either left or right)
        while (x >= minX && x < maxX && chars.Count > 0)
        {
            resultMatrix[y, x] = chars.Dequeue();                                
            x += direction;
        }

        x -= direction; // undo the last one
        y += direction; // offset spiral
        if (direction > 0) minY++; // reduce boundaries
        if (direction < 1) maxY--;            

        // going vertically (up or down)
        while (y >= minY && y < maxY && chars.Count > 0)
        {
            resultMatrix[y, x] = chars.Dequeue();
            y += direction;
        }

        y -= direction; // undo the last one
        if (direction > 0) maxX--; // reduce boundaries
        if (direction < 1) minX++;

        direction *= -1;
        x += direction; // offset spiral
    }

    StringBuilder inOrder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < resultMatrix.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < resultMatrix.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            inOrder.Append(resultMatrix[i, j]);
        }
    }

    // SENDOONHSPLE
    Console.WriteLine(inOrder);
    Console.ReadKey();

}
```

Comment: ,thank u for this code but I want to correct my code to be able to print in this form if i enter for ex: SENDHELPSOON must print sendhelpsoon  ,can u correct my code please

Comment: @rose not really no, you should have given the actual input and output of your code, but as far as i can see, the algorithm is wrong - extended above to explain